# multidimensional array search in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supposed I have two array like this

> var arr1 = [['1','2','3'],['1','4','7'],['1','5','9'],['2','5','8'],['3','5','7'],['3','6','9'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']];
>
> var arr2 = [1,3,5,7];
>
> var a = 0;

Now I want to search each arr2 value with the set of arr1 value using for loop in javascript, and whenever it's match with the arr1 set, 1 will be added to the variable a.

Note: I just want to match the arr1 pattern with loops.

My attempted code is here :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
var myarr = [
 ['1','2','3'],
 ['1','4','7'],
 ['1','5','9'],
 ['2','5','8'],
 ['3','5','7'],
 ['3','6','9'],
 ['4','5','6'],
 ['7','8','9']
];
 

 
 
var firstplayerarray=[];
var secondplayerarray=[];
var firstplayer = true;
var secondplayer = false;
var x = "X";
var o = "O";
var a = 0;
var b = 0; 

 
 
$(".box").click(function(){

var boxs = $(this).text();  
if(firstplayer && boxs == ""){
var firstplayerindmain = $(this).index()+1;
var firstplayerind = firstplayerindmain.toString();
$(this).text(x);
firstplayer = false;
secondplayer = true;
firstplayerarray.push(firstplayerind);
}
else if(secondplayer && boxs == ""){
var secondplayerindmain = $(this).index()+1;
var secondplayerind = secondplayerindmain.toString(); 
$(this).text(o);
firstplayer = true;
secondplayer = false;
secondplayerarray.push(secondplayerind);
}
else{} 

 
var i=0;
 
for(var k = b; k < 8; k++){ 
for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){ 
 
if(firstplayerarray[k] == myarr[i][j]){ 
a += 1;   
}  
}
};
  
b += 1;
alert("b is"+ b);
alert("a is"+ a);
});
 

console.log(myarr); 
console.log(firstplayerarray); 
console.log(secondplayerarray); 
 
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
 height: 100%
}
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 height: 100%;
}
p {
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 7vw;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 display: none
}
button {
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 2vw;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: none
}
.show {
 display: block
}
.hide {
 display: none !important;
}
.box {
 border: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 6vw;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: 33.333%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p></p>
  <button>Start New Game</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like below,

```js
let arr1 = [
  ['1', '2', '3'],
  ['1', '4', '7'],
  ['1', '5', '9'],
  ['2', '5', '8'],
  ['3', '5', '7'],
  ['3', '6', '9'],
  ['4', '5', '6'],
  ['7', '8', '9']
];
let arr2 = [1, 3, 5, 7];
let a = 0;
let arr = [].concat(...arr1);
let s = new Set(arr);
for (let i in arr2) {
  if (s.has(arr2[i] + '')) {
    a++;
  }
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

An other example using nested loops :

```js
var arr1 = [['1','4','7'],['1','5','9'], ['2','5','8'],['3','5','7'],['3','6','9'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']];
var arr2 = [1,3,5,7];
var a = 0;

// the big loop for arr1
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
 // second loop for arr1 subarrays
 for (var j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; ++j) {
  // an other loop inside arr2
  a += $.grep(arr2, function (elem) {
   return elem == arr1[i][j];
  }).length; // Returns number of occurrences 
 }
}
// Print results
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```